# Shifting elements in a div with overflow auto

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am experiencing problem with the layout of a page where my controls are shifting when I attempt to change the class using a javascript event.  Can anyone help with some ideas around the problem.  It only seems to be a problem in IE when the left scroll bar appears.

Here is an example of the html

```
<div id="container" style="overflow:auto;">
  <div id="control1Container" style="left:17%;top:145px;display:inline;position:absolute;">
     <div id="control1" class="listOUT" >I am a control</div>
  </div>
  <div id="control2Container" style="left:67%;top:145px;display:inline;position:absolute;">
     <div id="control2" class="listOUT" >I am a control</div>
  </div><!-- more controls here -->
</div>
```

So now the imagine that the controls within the container div take up enough space that the overflow margin appears on the left i.e. the controls extend below the bottom of the container div.  If I attempt to change the listOUT class on control1 to say listIN using javascript the control will shift to the left.  To me it almost seems like the browser is readjusting the control1Container to a new location that is 17% if the container div's new width with the scrollbar in place.

Any idea's?

Comment: dispaly = display? And your scrollbars appear for what element?

Comment: The scrollbar appears for the container element.  The control1Container element shifts to the left when the class is changed using javascripts

Comment: one other thing: display:inline effectively is display:block for elements positioned other than static.

Comment: Resuduum above says that you have a type in your example above .. in the inline styles you have mistyped display as dispaly ..

Comment: The container element should not get scrollbars at all, as control1container and control2container are both positioned absolutely and therefore are outside the regular page flow. Somehow your script seems to break the absolute positioning of the controls, but I have no idea without seeing the implementation of the class switch and the css definition of listIN and listOUT (or a demo page).

Comment: I am working on creating a quick sample document that show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give to the container div `position:relative`, so that the absolute positioned elements inside it get positioned in relation to it ..